# iOS get the subviews bounds when rotation happened

Tags: objective-c, viewcontroller, viewdidlayoutsubviews

Once rotated the phone, how can I get subview's final bounds?

As said, I rewrite the viewDidLayoutSubview method but only get the self.view's final bounds, the subview are using auto layout to positioning. So is there a way to get the subviews final bounds. and for some reason better not to subclass the view itself.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get bounds in that method:

`- (void)layoutSubviews;`

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway to avoid subclassing the view?

Comment: you could use this delegate without subclassing a view